# Java Execute external exe

Tags: java

I have this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("toolUpdate.exe", null, new File(location));
```

And I get the following error:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "toolUpdate.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\blah\AppData\Roaming"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

If I look at the directory I can see the file that I want to execute, I just can't get it to execute using that piece of code above.

This worked for me :

```
    String folder = location;
    String exe = "test.exe";
    ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
    p.command(folder + exe);
    p.start();
```

Comment: Have you checked for typos? Is the file exactly spelled as in your code?

Comment: It is exactly how it is spelled in the code.

Comment: Does that exe require UAC access to run?

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: Using process builder worked for me. Updated OP with my code.

Comment: @Ben if you solved your issue, I suggest you post the solution as an answer (you can answer your own question, it is encouraged; please read [Help center: Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Ben please post your update as an *answer* and delete your answer code from the question - that way others can immediately see there's an "answer"

Comment: @Ben You might like to have a look at the `ProcessBuillder#directory` property as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the method 1 with following code change.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(location + "toolUpdate.exe");
```